# Method SI_Score() for SI_PositionalColor - Oracle Multimedia

Tags: image, oracle, colors, multimedia

When I perform image comparing by using positional color with method SI_Score() for SI_PositionalColor:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE score DOUBLE PRECISION;
        myimage SI_StillImage;
        myPosColor SI_PositionalColor;
BEGIN
   SELECT positional_color INTO myPosColor 
   FROM PM.SI_MEDIA WHERE product_id=1;

   SELECT product_photo INTO myimage 
   FROM PM.SI_MEDIA WHERE product_id=2;

   score := myPosColor.SI_Score(myimage);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Score is ' || score);
END;
```

the result is 0.054611474275589 for the following images: [click here](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A88786_01/mm_cbr.htm#606783)

I have expected that the images are not so similar with respect to their positional colors.

The positional colors of these images are computed by applying SI_PositionalColor:

```
DECLARE myPosColor SI_PositionalColor;
        myimage    SI_StillImage;
BEGIN
   SELECT product_photo INTO myimage 
   FROM PM.SI_MEDIA WHERE product_id=1 FOR UPDATE;

   myPosColor := NEW SI_PositionalColor(myimage);
   UPDATE PM.SI_MEDIA 
      SET positional_color = myPosColor 
   WHERE product_id=1;

   COMMIT;
END;
```

and have the following values:

First image:
ORDSYS.SI_POSITIONALCOLOR(ORDSYS.COLORPOSITIONS(ORDSYS.SI_COLOR(0,0,0),ORDSYS.SI_COLOR(0,0,0),ORDSYS.SI_COLOR(0,0,0),ORDSYS.SI_COLOR(0,0,0),ORDSYS.SI_COLOR(234,29,37),ORDSYS.SI_COLOR(0,0,0),ORDSYS.SI_COLOR(0,0,0),ORDSYS.SI_COLOR(0,0,0),ORDSYS.SI_COLOR(0,0,0)))

Second image:
ORDSYS.SI_POSITIONALCOLOR(ORDSYS.COLORPOSITIONS(ORDSYS.SI_COLOR(0,0,0),ORDSYS.SI_COLOR(0,0,0),ORDSYS.SI_COLOR(0,0,0),ORDSYS.SI_COLOR(0,0,0),ORDSYS.SI_COLOR(49,93,164),ORDSYS.SI_COLOR(0,0,0),ORDSYS.SI_COLOR(0,0,0),ORDSYS.SI_COLOR(0,0,0),ORDSYS.SI_COLOR(0,0,0)))

I don't unerstand why black color (0,0,0) appears for 8 areas in the second image rather than white (255, 255, 255).

Any ideas why this might be happening?